# What are good methods in printing Extended ASCII characters for C?

Tags: c, loops, character, ascii, extended-ascii

First I would like to see what ASCII printable characters in C look like.

The following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    for (char a = 32; a < 127; a++)
        printf("a=%c\n", a); 
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    for (unsigned char a = 32; a < 127; a++)
        printf("a=%c\n", a); 
    return 0;
}
```

The above two code snippets work nicely, telling me about ASCII printable characters.

Now next I would like to have a look at Extended ASCII characters for C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    for (unsigned char a = 128; a < 256; a++)
        printf("a=%c\n", a); 

    return 0;
}
```

Then comes the endless loop with unknown strange characters.

Where did I do wrong?

I thought loop would stop when a reaches 256, but it didn't.

And where did strange characters come from?

How can I print Extended ASCII characters for C?

Comment: What is the maximum value of an unsigned char? Not 256.

Comment: `unsigned char a` --> `unsigned a` or `int a`.

Comment: There is no guarantee a C implementation/environment uses ASCII at all.

Comment: For characters to have meaning, you should have in mind which Extended ASCII character set you're working with. "Extended ASCII" is a characteristic of certain character encodings but you can only work with one character encoding at a time..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an infinite loop because the maximum value representable by an `unsigned char` is 255<sup>1</sup>, and incrementing it past that point causes it to wrap around to zero, so the condition `a < 256` is always true.  Your program will work as you intended if you use `int` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    for (int a = 128; a < 256; a++)
        printf("a=%c\n", a); 
    return 0;
}
```

It is perfectly fine to pass an `int` to printf's `%c`,<sup>2</sup> as long as its *value* is in the range representable by `unsigned char`, which it is.

However, if you run this program on a modern computer, you're still likely to get "strange characters".  For instance, when I run it on my computer I get 128 lines of

```
a=�
```

This is because a *modern* computer's CLI windows expect UTF-8-encoded Unicode text, and in UTF-8, all the characters above U+007F are encoded using more than one byte.  So the terminal emulator receives what it thinks of as an invalid, incomplete byte sequence one each line, and it prints a special "replacement character" for them.  The simplest way to see the *actual* characters in the U+0080..U+00FF range is to use C's "wide characters":

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    for (int a = 128; a < 256; a++)
        wprintf(L"U+%04X = '%lc'\n", a, (wchar_t)a);
    return 0;
}
```

`wprintf` takes care of converting from wide characters to whatever text encoding the environment expects.  This is not guaranteed to work, because C's "wide characters" are underspecified and ill-designed to the point where I actually recommend people do *not* use them in production code (instead, use exclusively narrow strings holding UTF-8), but for a test program like this you can usually get away with it.  I get output like this:

```
U+0080 = ''
U+0081 = ''
U+0082 = ''
...
U+00A0 = ' '
U+00A1 = '¡'
U+00A2 = '¢'
...
U+00FD = 'ý'
U+00FE = 'þ'
U+00FF = 'ÿ'
```

You could get something different, if your computer is insufficiently modern.  The U+0080..U+009F range is yet more useless control characters, which is why those are not showing anything.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically [0, 255] is the *minimum* required range for `unsigned char`; the C standard allows for the possibility that it can represent a larger range, e.g. [0, 511].  If you had run your program on a computer where `unsigned char` had that range, it would have worked.  However, no one has manufactured such a computer in many years.  If you really want to worry about it, include `<limits.h>` and verify that `CHAR_BIT` is 8 and/or that `UCHAR_MAX` is 255.

<sup>2</sup> Technically, thanks to a vestigial feature of C called "default argument promotion", you *always* pass an `int` to `%c`, even if the variable you supply has a character type.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
a < 256
```

is always `true` as `unsigned char` valid range is <0, 255>.

Answer (score 0):

The loop

```
for (unsigned char a = 128; a < 256; a++)
```

runs forever on your platform since 255 + 1 is 0 due to *wrap around* of an `unsigned` type. You *could* use the confusing (when you see it for the first time)

```
for (unsigned char a = 128; a >= 128; a++)
```

What gets printed to your console will depend on the *encoding* your system uses (*probably* ASCII), along with how your terminal prints characters in that range.